# Failed to fetch archive in apt

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, error-handling

I am getting the below error while trying to install RSS software

1. Liferea
2. Evolution

Facing problem for both. But I want only one.
Error code:

> 404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80] Fetched 10.6 kB in 2s (6,464
> B/s)
>
> E: Failed to fetch
> http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/liferea/liferea_1.12.6-1_amd64.deb
> 404  Not Found [IP: 43.255.166.254 80] E: Unable to fetch some
> archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I have used below some commands but still no result.

```
sudo apt-get install liferea
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-rss
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The file does not exist, just as it states.

[image: Obi-Wan problem]

Optional manual install: go to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/liferea/ (i.e. the URL from your error without the specific file part) and pick the desired `...amd64.deb` for your package.

Download and then install via

```
sudo dpkg -i <deb-file>
```